# "ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches" error when no nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm migrating a project from one codebase to another to clean up a lot of accumulated cruft, shift to a new presentation layer, etc.

One of the relationships is the canonical `User has_many Order`, which I have expressed as nested resources in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  resources :orders
end
```

and so I have the named route `user_orders_path(@user)`.  It works just fine if the user has orders, but if the user has no orders, trying to render the route gives the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"orders", 
:user_id=>#<User id: 472, account_id: nil, first_name: "Denis", last_name: 
"Haskin", ...etc... , last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1">})
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `raise_routing_error'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:528:in `rescue in generate'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:520:in `generate'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:561:in `generate'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:586:in `url_for'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
from /Users/dwhsix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@zmx2/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:213:in `user_orders_path'
from (irb):24
```

(I'm providing the full stack trace from testing this in `rails console`; for some reason I'm not getting full stack trace for this error in the server log.)

I'm sort of at a loss to explain (and fix) this, and I was hoping this might ring a bell with someone.  I tested this in a new empty project and of course it works fine.  I guess the next thing I'll try is to strip down as much as I can about these models and the controller, and start adding pieces back until the error recurs.  Because I'm migrating over existing code, it's very difficult to isolate this to a small piece of example code.

(At the risk of possibly confusing the issue, I have started using Ryan Bates' [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/) in this project and I'm a little suspicious that it might be playing a role here, but I did strip it out and test without it, with no change in this incorrect behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user/orders relationship was a complete red herring, as it turns out.  `user.rb` had a `to_param` method:

```
def to_param
  login
end
```

which was returning nil for some users.  This is what caused the named route helper to fail.  It just happened there was a high correlation between users that did not have orders and users for whom `to_param` returned nil, and this error first showed up when I started trying to integrate order display for users.